# When I've signed a key with GPG, how do I send this information to a keyserver?

Tags: pgp

I just signed a friend's public key using `gpg --sign-key`. How can I send the signed key back to the key server, so that other people can see that I've signed it?

Comment: I would argue that you shouldn't send other people's keys to keyservers. Rather, send the signed key back to the owner and let the owner decide how it should be distributed. I've heard of people who specifically choose to avoid uploading to some key servers in an attempt to avoid spam, and it could be considered rude to publish someone's info without their consent.

Answer (score 3):

Use `gpg --send-keys`.

Comment: How do you find and specify the key to export?

Comment: `gpg --list-signatures` shows the id of all your signed keys